# If Then Loop with Search in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I am currently doing a "if then" loop in excel with following logic.

Value to Check

**1. S9(7) C3

 2. S9(11)V9(2) C3

 3. X(3)**

Logic I have used

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S9",D1,1)),CONCATENATE("s370fpd",5,".","0"),CONCATENATE("$ebcdic",5,"."))
```

Now problem here is that **S9** maybe of two types. In the first one i.e. **S9(7) C3**
it works fine but for second one i.e. **S9(11)V9(2) C3** I have to CONCATENATE "s370fpd" with value inside bracket of V9 i.e. 2 in this case. So it will become **"s370fpd5.2"**.

Since the value inside bracket is dynamic hence the logic has to search inside it. I am not sure how it will check and then append it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but keeping as much as what you have right now as possible, I would use this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S9",D1,1)),CONCATENATE("s370fpd",5,".",IFERROR(MID(D1,SEARCH("V9",D1)+3,SEARCH(")",D1,SEARCH("V9",D1))-SEARCH("V9",D1)-3),"0")),CONCATENATE("$ebcdic",5,"."))
```

I substituted `"0"` with

```
IFERROR(MID(D1,SEARCH("V9",D1)+3,SEARCH(")",D1,SEARCH("V9",D1))-SEARCH("V9",D1)-3),"0")
```

which is what gets what's between brackets after `V9`.

It also appears to me that you can turn `CONCATENATE("$ebcdic",5,".")` into `"$ebcdic5."` directly and `CONCATENATE("s370fpd",5,"."` into `CONCATENATE("s370fpd5."`, and/or use `&` to make things a little shorter, but that's only subject to what you've put in your question:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S9",D1,1)),"s370fpd5."&IFERROR(MID(D1,SEARCH("V9",D1)+3,SEARCH(")",D1,SEARCH("V9",D1))-SEARCH("V9",D1)-3),"0"),"$ebcdic5.")
```

Comment: Jerry, Very elegant solution. Kudos to your trick and knowledge.